# sitecore image map editor validation issue

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor

In Sitecore when I create an Image Map and save it in Rich Text Editor, it gives me a XHTML Validation error. Does anyone has any ideas to overcome this?

Comment: It would be good to see the code and errors. And who gives you this- content editor or ...?

Answer (score 0):

By default the global validation item includes "Full Page XHtml" so navigate to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Global Rules` and remove the Full Page XHtml from 2 of the 4 selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mark..If I apply the above rule it applies globally whereas my requirement is to just apply locally.(just for 1 item)...

Comment: I understand, but you cannot override locally. That global rule is what is messing you up. By design, it applies to everything. Get what I mean?